# How to find cumulative product for data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a (triangular)data frame
i,e:DF1:

```
      12-24  24-36  36-48
2017  1.554  3.532  8.657
2018  2.978  1.114   NaN
2019  4.366   NaN    NaN
```

I've to find the **cumprod** for this dataframe.

I tried this code:

```
df2= df1.iloc[:, ::-1].cumprod(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]
```

But result is same as df1

The result should look like:

```
      12-24  24-36  36-48
2017  8.898  4.646  8.657
2018  7.344  1.114   NaN
2019  4.366   NaN    NaN
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
>>> df1.iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
      12-24  24-36  36-48
2017  8.898  4.646  8.657
2018  7.344  1.114    NaN
2019  4.366    NaN    NaN
>>>
```

You don't need an `axis=1` and extra colons.

Doing `df1.iloc[:, ::-1]` would reverse the columns instead of the rows.